# How to implement Invite Facebook friends functionality as in Gowalla using Facebook API?

Tags: facebook

How to implement Invite Facebook friends functionality as in Gowalla?

'Invite your Facebook friends to join you"

Url: http://gowalla.com/friends/add/facebook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't want to register on that site just to see it, but I am pretty sure they are using [`fb:request-form`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/request-form). You can see an example how to implement it [here](http://fbrell.com/xfbml/fb%3aserver-fbml-multi-friend-selector) (if this link doesn't work go to http://fbrell.com/, click on examples and select `fb:server-fbml-multi-friend-selector`)

Comment: It does not seem to be there anymore.